# Why are base constructors are in static context? How to cope?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, static, idisposable

Take this code for example:

```
public class DisposeMe : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm disposed!");
    }
}

public class Base
{
    private readonly Object _object;

    public Base(Object obj)
    {
        _object = obj;
    }
}

public class Derived : Base, IDisposable
{
    public Derived()
        : base(new DisposeMe())
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Should dispose the object allocated in the constructor.
    }
}
```

I have this kind of code in an actual program.

What I would actually like to do is replace the `new DisposeMe()` in the `Derived` constructor, into a method that would create & return it, but also save it in a field in the process, so I could dispose it at `Derived.Dispose`.

However I can't, because for some reason (beyond me) the constructor accessed by `base` is static. Why? How can I get around it?

P.S. I'm aware I could change `Base` to be `IDisposable` and let it check if the object fed is `IDisposable` every time it is disposed itself. I'm **not** interested in doing that. It's cumbersome, inefficient and most importantly the one who allocated the object should be the one responsible for disposing it (otherwise I'd be shooting myself in the foot disposing an object that's in use someplace else).

Comment: Where would you put that factory method (the one which should create an `IDisposable`)? Can you provide some sample code which demonstrates your intention? Note that you can't use an *instance method* of `Derived`, as your instance is *still being constructed* when you call the `Derived` constructor.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Oh I see the problem now. So what the solution might be? I must have a reference in-order to dispose. Do I need to change my design? if so into something like what?

Comment: _the one who allocated the object should be the one responsible ..._ Yes, exactly. And it shouldn't be the responsibility of Base to store it. You simply shouldn't have this problem. Consider it a messagte: your basic design is flawed. \

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add protected read-only property into `Base` so you can access it from `Derived.Dispose`.

```
public class DisposeMe : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm disposed!");
    }
}

public class Base
{
    private readonly Object _object;
    protected Object _Object { get { return _object; } }

    public Base(Object obj)
    {
        _object = obj;
    }
}

public class Derived : Base, IDisposable
{
    public Derived()
        : base(new DisposeMe())
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        (_Object as IDisposable).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Was afraid to do it (I'm very secretive when it comes to OOP), but other option is to save the same reference twice, one for use and one for disposal. You win fate ;_; Thank you Euphoric!

Comment: @Ken I don't think there is anything wrong by exposing read-only data in a class. The problems start when you can change them.

Comment: Oh I mean what drew me back is just making it protected. @Steve in the actual case it's guaranteed to be `IDisposable` although I did check it for null in the actual project. Thank you both.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the "replace `new DisposeMe()` with a method call", right? Anyway, you could make `Base` generic so you don't need the cast in `Dispose`. Also, it sufficed to simply make `_object` protected instead, but adding a protected property may be more flexible (if you need to override it or something).

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Yeah, but it solves the general problem. Also, I'm trying to not use generics whenever I can. Yeah, you can make field protected if it is readonly.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most simple way is to make a factory for your `Derived` class:

```
public static Derived CreateDerived()
{
   DisposeMe d = new DisposeMe();
   return new Derived(d);
}

private DisposeMe _d;
private Derived(DisposeMe d) : base (d) 
{
    _d = d;
}
```

and then your dispose method:

```
public void Dispose()
{
   _d.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: If the constructor throws an exception, you'll leak the `new DisposeMe`.  I think it would be better to do something like `Derived result = null; try {result = new DisposeMe(d); } finally {if (result == null) d.Dispose();} return result;`; too bad there's not a nicer pattern for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Derived<T> : Base, IDisposable where T : IDisposable, new()
{
    public Derived()
        : base(new T())
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var obj = base._object as IDisposable;
        if (obj != null)
            obj.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: `_object` is not visible to `Derived`. It's `private`. The accepted answer solved does make it possible tho, but thank you.